# How to use two middleware in ASP.NET Core application

Tags: firebase, asp.net-core, authentication, jwt

I use this Firebase auth middleware in my app to validate bearer token. But I need another middleware for admin to login in group (group works as individual user) and I need to authenticate it.

Is there any way to have two of these pieces of middleware?

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.Audience = "your-firebase-app-id";
    options.Authority = "https://securetoken.google.com/your-firebase-app-id";
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using authorization policy may allow you to protect api by either authentication method. 
For instance, you could add another cookie authentication method by following for a test.
`CookieController.cs` for login and logout.

```
        [HttpGet("cookielogin")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Authenticate([FromQuery]string usr, [FromQuery]string pwd)
        {
            if (usr == "admin" && pwd == "123") //simple logic to check username and password 
            {
                var userClaims = new List<Claim>()
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, usr),
                };

                var userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(userClaims,CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                var userPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentity);

                await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, userPrincipal);
                return Ok("login success, cookie create");
            }            
            return Unauthorized("login failed");
        }

        [HttpGet("cookielogout")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
        {
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            return Ok("logout ,cookie delete");
        }
```

program.cs

```
//Cookie login authentication
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

//Your Jwtbearer
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                     .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>{...}
                     );

//Add a policy called "Jwt_Or_Cookie" to allow either jwt or cookie.
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Jwt_Or_Cookie", policy =>
    {
        policy.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        policy.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();

    });
});
```

On top of controller or Action to set `[Authorize()]` attribute.

```
        [Authorize(Policy = "Jwt_Or_Cookie")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {...}
```

Test
[image]

Comment: Used this as my solution, Thanks.